# Is it possible to input a collection info node into the raycast node?

Tags: geometry-nodes, collections

For now, I am only able to input multiple objects by either joining them, or manually joining their *Object Info* nodes with a *Join Geometry* node.

[image: Here is the current manual method.]

I would like to simply be able to drag objects in and out of a folder for them to show up instead, hence why I would like to use the *Collection Info* node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

- Just put your objects into a collection.
- Use the node `Collection Info` and activate the option *Separate Children*. This splits the objects into single available instances.
- Use the node `Realize Instances`, which converts all instances into a geometry that you can use with the node `Raycast`.

[image]